# Send Body as raw using Guzzle

Tags: php, http, guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to use Guzzle to send POST request to my web service. this service accepts body as raw. It works fine when I use postman but I doesn't using Guzzle. when using Guzzle, I get only the webservice description as I put the web service URL in the browser.
 here is my code:

```
    $body = "CA::Read:PackageItems  (CustomerId='xxxxxx',AllPackages=TRUE);";
    $headers = [
        ....
        ....

    ]; 
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://172.19.34.67:9882/TisService',$headers,$body);
echo $body = $response->getBody();
```

seems headers or body doesn't pass through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://172.19.34.67:9882/TisService',['headers' => $headers, 'body' => $body]);
```

Comment: _try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: But it's better than nothing

Answer (score 2):

I have recently had to implement `Guzzle` for the first time and it is a fairly simple library to use.

First I created a new Client

```
// Passed in our options with just our base_uri in
$client = new Client(["base_uri" => "http://example.com"]);
```

I then created a `POST` request, not how I am using  `new Request` instead of `$client->request(...` though. This doesn't really matter to much that I've used `new Request` though.

```
// Create a simple request object of type 'POST' with our remaining URI
// our headers and the body of our request.
$request = new Request('POST', '/api/v1/user/', $this->_headers, $this->body);
```

so in essence it would look like:

```
$request = new Request('POST', '/api/v1/user/', ['Content-Type' => "application/json, 'Accept' => "application/json"], '{"username": "myuser"}');
```

`$this->headers` is a simple key-value pair array of our request headers making sure to set the `Content-Type` header and `$this->body` is a simple string object, in my case it forms a JSON body.

I can simply then just call the `$client->send(...` method to send the request like:

```
// send would return us our ResponseInterface object as long as an exception wasn't thrown.
$rawResponse = $client->send($request, $this->_options);
```

`$this->_options` is a simple key-value pair array again simple to the `headers` array but this includes things like `timeout` for the request.

For me I have created a simple `Factory` object called `HttpClient` that constructs the whole `Guzzle` request for me this is why I just create a new `Request` object instead of calling `$client->request(...` which will also send the request.

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially need to do to send data as raw is to json_encode an array of your `$data` and send it in the request `body`.

```php
$request = new Request(
    'POST',
    $url,
    ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
    \GuzzleHttp\json_encode($data)
);

$response = $client->send($request);
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Using guzzle Request `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;` and Client `GuzzleHttp\Client`